# progressDeadlineSeconds is not correctly timing out

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have progressDeadlineSeconds set to 120 seconds

I deploy and run `kubectl rollout status deployment mydeployment`

The deployment failed with `0 of 1 updated replicas available - CrashLoopBackOff`

But the kubectl is still hanging forever with message: `Waiting for deployment "mydeployment" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...`

Why is this happening, progressDeadlineSeconds is suppose to force it to fail and cause `kubectl rollout status deployment` to exit with a non-zero return code right?

Comment: Could you please share your deployment yaml by editing the question?

Comment: And what is your version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct, `kubectl rollout status` returns a non-zero exit code if the Deployment has exceeded the progression deadline. [Progress Deadline Seconds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds):

> `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` is an optional field that specifies
>   the number of seconds you want to wait for your Deployment to progress
>   before the system reports back that the Deployment has failed
>   progressing - surfaced as a condition with `Type=Progressing`,
>   `Status=False`. and `Reason=ProgressDeadlineExceeded` in the status of
>   the resource. The Deployment controller will keep retrying the
>   Deployment. This defaults to 600. In the future, once automatic
>   rollback will be implemented, the Deployment controller will roll back
>   a Deployment as soon as it observes such a condition.
>
> If specified, this field needs to be greater than
>   `.spec.minReadySeconds`.

Which brings us to [Min Ready Seconds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#min-ready-seconds)

> `.spec.minReadySeconds` is an optional field that specifies the
>   minimum number of seconds for which a newly created Pod should be
>   ready without any of its containers crashing, for it to be considered
>   available. This defaults to 0 (the Pod will be considered available as
>   soon as it is ready).

Without your exact deployment configs it is hard to tell where the problem is but there are few things to check out:

- Try setting both the `progressDeadlineSeconds` and `minReadySeconds` remembering that the later must have a smaller value.
- `progressDeadlineSeconds` might not be respected when used with `Replicas: 1`. Check your `maxUnavailable` param in order to see if it allows deployment full unavailability.
- As a workaround you can specify a timeout period for your `kubectl rollout status` command. For example: `kubectl rollout status deployment mydeployment --timeout=120s`
- If you don't want to wait for the rollout to finish then you can use `--watch=false`. You will than have to check the status manually by running `kubectl describe deployment` and `kubectl get deployment` commands which might not be ideal.

Please let me know if that helps.